# Android WorkManager has error when testing with Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric, android-workmanager

I'm using Android work manager with a custom initialization. to do that i disable auto-initialization in the manifest like this

```
        <provider
        tools:replace="android:authorities"
        android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.work_manager_init"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:exported="false" />
```

And in application code I use this code

```
private fun initWorkManager() {
    WorkManager.initialize(this, Configuration.Builder().run {
        setWorkerFactory(appComponent.daggerWorkerFactory())
        build()
    })
}
```

And it works fine when I run my application. But when I'm testing with roboletric any class that needs the context by `RuntimeEnvironment.application` throws this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is already initialized.  
Did you try to initialize it manually without disabling 
WorkManagerInitializer? See WorkManager#initialize(Context, 
Configuration) or the class levelJavadoc for more information.
```

The `initWorkManager()` get calls and throw this beacuse it doesn't know auto-init is already disabled in the manifest and somehow my test cannot read the values from the manifest file.

Any help or suggestion will be appritiated.

Comment: Which version of Robolectric are you using? Did you specify a special manifest file to be used by your tests? Did you maybe override the manifest in your test/ directory? You could also try to only initialize Workmanager by yourself if it is NOT a robolectric test.

Comment: I have this problem also, except my application does not require a custom initialization. 
If I manually call `WorkManager.initialize()` as above I get the same error.
If I *don't* call initialize(), I instead get ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is not initialized properly. The most likely cause is that you disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest but forgot to call WorkManager#initialize in your Application#onCreate or a ContentProvider.`` 

It seems like there's not a good way out of this. It complains whether or not initialize() is called. Catch 22.

Comment: I have exactly same problem. I disabled the default inicialization via Manifest and it works when I run the app normally but when I run the Roboelectric test it fails with the error you mentioned.

Comment: Anyone found a solution/workaround?

Answer (score 10):

I solved a similar issue with the help of the Androidx Work Manager testing utils. For reference see the docs here: [Android work manager testing docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/testing)

Basically what you need to do is add a dependency to include the work manger test utils:

```
testImplementation 'androidx.work:work-testing:2.0.1'
```

Then you will be able to call code in your test setup similar to this:

```
final Configuration config = new Configuration.Builder()
    .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.DEBUG)
    .setExecutor(new SynchronousExecutor())
    .build();
WorkManagerTestInitHelper.initializeTestWorkManager(
    context, config);
```

Whereas the context could obtained in different ways, depending on your test infrastructure.

With this approach no other steps like excluding something from the manifest are necessary.